# attributeError 'tkinter.app' object has no attribute, where I defined method inside classs

Tags: python, tkinter

My code gives me an error of   `File "C:\pythonPro\...widgets.py", line 109, in openNewWindow self.btn_submit=self.button_creation(self.newWindow) File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2383, in __getattr__ return getattr(self.tk, attr) AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'button_creation'`

where I call inside a class `CustomWidgets` one function `button_creation()` -> I guess it should be a method as it is inside class from another function `openNewWindow` .

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class CustomWidgets():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        menubar = MenuBar(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)

    def button_creation(self,window=None):
        self.btn_0=Button(master=window)
        self.btn_0.pack(expand='YES')
        return self.btn_0

    def openNewWindow(self,Mainwindow=None):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(Mainwindow)
        self.frmbutton = Frame(master=self.newWindow)
        self.frmbutton.place(y=75)
        self.btn_submit=self.button_creation(self.newWindow) #Error giving line
        self.btn_submit.configure(text='SUBMIT')

class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        fileMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="Menu",underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Email Configuration", underline=1, command=lambda : CustomWidgets.openNewWindow(parent))

if __name__=='__main__':
       f=CustomWidgets()
       f.root.mainloop()
```

I want to understand why method `button_creation` is read by python as an attribute `self.button_creation(self.newWindow)`?

Comment: The code you posted cannot give the error you say it does. Nothing in your code ever calls `openNewWindow`. Please follow the instructions at [mcve] for creating an example.

Comment: I modified code, but it also doesnot run to give an error. I can post all code, but it can be long

Comment: We don’t want all the code, but code that doesn’t reproduce the error isn’t very useful.

Comment: Now, it runs and when user clicks, menu->Email configuration. the error shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you're calling the method on the class rather than on an instance of the class. When you do `CustomWidgets.openNewWindow(parent)`, `parent` is being passed as the `self` parameter. `parent` is an instance of `Tk`, and an instance of `Tk` doesn't have a `button_creation` method just as the error is telling you.

The normal way to solve this is to call the function on an instance of the class rather than on the class itself, or you need to define the method as a class method rather than an instance method. Since your methods depend on `self`, you'll likely want to continue to use it as an instance method since class methods don't have a "self".

First, pass the instance of `CustomWidgets` in to `MenuBar`:

```
class CustomWidgets():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        menubar = MenuBar(self.root, custom_widgets = self)
        ...
```

Next, modify `MenuBar` to accept this as a parameter, save the value, and then use it in the menu command.

```
class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, custom_widgets=None):
        ...
        self.cw = custom_widgets
        ...
        fileMenu.add_command(..., command=lambda : self.cw.openNewWindow(parent))
```

Comment: hard to grasp, parallelly looking for Methods Are Objects:Bound or Unbound from Mark Lutz . Thanks

Comment: From curiosity and as I said still reading on class and oop issues. I f I add `@classmethod ` ahead of `button_creation` method and replace `self` with `cls` my previous code, is there chance it would work. For info, I am using your code now, questions are for better understanding the issue

Comment: @xlmaster: yes, you can use class methods in that way.